# WPF: An application does not crash if an exception occurs in Loaded event

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have created a new WPF application and added an event handler for Loaded event in MainWindow:

```
Loaded += (s, e) => { throw new Exception("AAAA!"); };
```

Then i start this application from Visual C# and the application doesn't crash nor show an uncaught exception.

I expect that it would crash and this application indeed crashes on other computers. But why does it work on mine?

**Update**
Added a screenshot:[image: screenshot]

Comment: Because the application is compiled for "Any CPU" and you're running a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: @Cody Gray it was compiled for x86 and i'm running a 64bit os. Changed it to "Any CPU" and the application crashed. Interesting.

Comment: Argh, I played with `Thread.Sleep` and now it doesn't crashes if it's compiled for "Any CPU".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Loaded event is propably called from a background thread. When an exception is thrown in this thread, it will be terminated, but will not affect your main application thread. This behaviour can be seen in many event handlers, e.g. a Timer_Elapsed event handler will also not affect your code generally.
This dows not mean you shouldn't care about the exceptions inside such code!

Comment: How can i check that? I added `Thread.Sleep(1000)` before throwing an exception and the whole window hangs for 1 sec. So i expect they are in the same thread.

Comment: you could try to copare Thread.Current with this.Dispatcher.Thread to detect this and/or check the result of this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess(). But maybe you don't have to, what do you want to achieve? (FU'2 the answers ans comments above mine, those seem to be on the same trail...)

Comment: As a developer, I want my application to crash if i haven't caught all exceptions. I don't want my application to keep running when something is broken. I also don't get why `Loaded` would be fired on another thread. I just tried this: `Loaded += (s, e) => { if (this.Dispatcher.Thread.Equals(Thread.CurrentThread)) Thread.Sleep(4000); throw new Exception("AAAA!"); };`. The window freezes for 4 seconds and then everything is fine, no "this application has stopped working" dialog.

Comment: wow, the exception being consumed even on the UI thread... does this only happen when run from within VS or even when started directly? I suppopse it hase something to do with the bittness of you application, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807122/wpf-showdialog-swallowing-exceptions-during-window-load) for hints...

Comment: thanks for the link. The solution in the answer works in 90% cases, but seems because 64bit machines unable to properly throw exceptions..

Answer (score 6):

To catch the exception you need to either do a try/catch in the Loaded method, or you can tell the Dispatcher to notify you when an unhandled exception occurs.

Try the following, for instance in the OnStartup method of your application:

```
App.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s,e) => 
{ 
  // Handle the exception here
  var ex = e.Exception; 
};
```

**Edit:**

If you want the application to crash then try the following:

```
App.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s,e) => 
{ 
  // this should cause your application to crash :-)
  throw new Exception("Now it should crash!", e.Exception);
};
```

The difference here is that we create a new exception that is thrown on the UI-thread.

Comment: Yes, I know. But why don't I see the standard Windows dialog "Application has stopped working" when i don't have `DispatcherUnhandledException`?

Comment: If you expect your app to crash then the exception must be raised on the ui thread. Try to raise a new exception inside the exception handler.

Comment: @meze: Updated my answer with a version that crashes :-)

Comment: @Rune Grimstad, updated my code and the application doesn't crash. The window stays displayed like nothing has happen. Added `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:/ex", "caught")` and `c:/ex` was created. So `DispatcherUnhandledException` was called.

Comment: @meze: Interesting. Did you throw a new exception inside DispatcherUnhandledException?

Comment: @Rune Grimstad: yes. If i throw it outside `DispatcherUnhandledException`, the application will crash. But won't if it's inside.

Comment: @meze: Interesting and surprising. It would be interesting to see your source code.

Comment: @Rune Grimstad: I decided to attach a screenshot with the code to my question ;)