# How to log all thrown exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, intellitrace

How to log any exceptions that were thrown and catched? Something like Visual Studio's IntelliTrace do. Or is there a way to integrate InteliTrace into debug version of application and then view its logs?

**Update:** I'll clarify that a bit. I want standard .txt (or any custom) logs, the format doesn't matter. The main point is I want to log all exceptions that occurred in all third-party libraries without adding code to them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I guess the feature you are searching for is called `FirstChanceException` and can be accessed via the 
[AppDomain.FirstChanceException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx)

Essentially this event provides a hook to get information about *any* (managed) exception getting thrown in the `AppDomain`. 
You can **not** handle the Exception this way! It is only a sort of notification

---

Update: 
regarding your comment about a "swallowed exception" on another answer - and just a shot into the dark:
On x64 systems exceptions that get thrown in a windows' onLoad method can not be caught in your Main() method.
see [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807122/wpf-showdialog-swallowing-exceptions-during-window-load) for reference

---

Update 2: 
As for `Threads` I think that you would have to implement it yourself. This would involve some sort of polling and would harm performance, but I guess for debugging it is OK in most cases.
This could be done using

```
var threads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;
```

Comment: That's it! Is there some similar way to discover when (and where) new threads are created?

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't think that there is a built-in event for this

Comment: @yas4891 Do you know of a way to filter the logged exceptions to only exceptions within my codebase? The FirstChanceExceptionHandler is logging exceptions thrown in 3rd party dlls

Answer (score 5):

You might go with aspects. If for example you take [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), and write an aspect that creates a try-catch for every function, logging is done in the aspect. After logging just rethrow it.

Example code from their website to have a complete answer with demo code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Aspect that, when applied on a method, catches all its exceptions,
/// assign them a GUID, log them, and replace them by an <see cref="InternalException"/>.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class ExceptionPolicyAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Method invoked upon failure of the method to which the current
    /// aspect is applied.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Information about the method being executed.</param>
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        Trace.TraceError("Exception {0} handled by ExceptionPolicyAttribute: {1}",
            guid, args.Exception.ToString());

        throw new InternalException(
            string.Format("An internal exception has occurred. Use the id {0} " +
                "for further reference to this issue.", guid));
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You could use any logger like log4net, NLog or the enterprise library ( my preferred way of doing logging and some other stuff ). But that isn't really the task here. The task is - IMHO - to inject logging into the project with as less manual coding as possible.

Answer (score 1):

try using Log4Net - its a great logger and used a lot in these scenarios http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4net/

Answer (score 1):

For handled exceptions you'd most likely need to log them explicitly. Even if that's not the case semantically there's a huge difference to handled and unhandled exceptions.

Handled exceptions are no longer an exceptional situation. Some one writing the code said. I know how to handle this exception and proceed correctly afterwards.

For unhandled exceptions have a look at [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

Comment: We having an obscure bug that has something to do with swallowed exception in third party library.

Comment: @Poma Does this "swallowing" happen in some "onLoad" method in WPF or WinForms?

Comment: No, it's about networking. Some function seems to send some trash to socket and swallow occurred error.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a debugger, like WinDbg, to your process, and get it to break on any first chance CLR exceptions; this will include exceptions in the third party library. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/08/24/managed-debugging-with-windbg-breaking-on-an-exception-part-1.aspx) for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own logging system or use third party lib called log4net.

Comment: But i guess the OP refferring to wanting logs in event viewer (in windows control panel). I dont know, i am assuming.

Comment: Poma,
You cant log for 3rd party libs unless they throw exceptions to you (the caller), just a reminder mate.

Comment: Yeah log4net is the best thing you could take... dont know any better logging Framework...

Comment: There is another 1 basedo n log4net in codeplex. i forgot the name. Dont know how far its better than log4net.

Comment: @zenwalker: this is only partially true. .NET provides a means to log **all** (managed) exceptions. See my answer for more information

Comment: @yas4891
Well that has a limitation that the 3rd party lib has to be a manged code. Any ways thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @zenwalker: you are right. That might be a bit misguiding. I'll update my comment and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Log4Net proposed by some guys, you could also use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). I don't know the differences between the two solutions, I just know that I'm happy with NLog.

Answer (score 0):

If your thing is a web thing then you can use https://elmah.github.io/ to automatically log errors (without even stopping your service!)